# Sentiment Analysis but for Descriptions in Texts?

Tags: natural-language, sentiment-analysis

Reviewing literature about sentiment analysis, I can only find contributions focussing on the sentiment of the author. Famous examples are twitter posts or movie reviews. I wonder if there are contributions that address the overall sentiment of a scene described in a book to find for example dangerous or calm situations depending on these descriptions.

Are custom models or datasets used to accomplish these tasks rather than being done with classic sentiment analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you would accomplish rating a scene or a book? You would have to give individual sentiment ratings/weights to the words and sentences within the text and come to a rating/sentiment. That is the same procedure as getting the emotion of a comment on twitter. The main difference is, that you probably have to weight a page or a whole paragraph in a book. But the procedure is the same. I believe there is not much research on that topic, as it is something that is strong related to a narrative tunnel and writing in general, as opinions, reviews and twitter comments are normally full of emotions, and their analysis is driven by business insight and therefore, how to get more money.

You can ask or present people a scene of a natural disaster and derive sentiments from word clouds etc.

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-981-15-1286-5_10

Movie scripts with tense scenes can be considered a book with scenes:
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-49161-1_36

On the book les miserable:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6892538/

Does this help you?

Comment: Thank you very much for these sources! They are very useful.

Comment: You are welcome!